# quicksight pie chart with values from same row

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Hey I'm new to AWS Quicksight and I'm wondering how to display a pie chart with values from the latest row.

Everyday I have a cronjob running counting the VM in different environments. My dataset is like that:

| Date | Vms in dev | Vms in test | Vms in preprod | Vms in prod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/10/2021 | 5 | 6 | 15 | 12 |
| 10/10/2021 | 5 | 6 | 15 | 12 |
| 11/10/2021 | 7 | 8 | 16 | 14 |

I would like a pie chart that shows the VMs in dev, test, preprod, prod only for the last day.
In this case, I will see a pie chart divided into 4 with values: 7, 8, 16, 14.

How to achieve that in AWS Quicksight?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change my dataset.

The dataset should be something like:

```
Date, VM name, environment
10/10/2021, vmA, dev
10/10/2021, vmB, dev
```

The cons is instead of having 1 row for a day, I have 1 row for each VMs.